# Login manageiq using REST API from external application

Tags: manageiq

Im trying to login to manageIQ using REST API from external application (internal app).

Currently im using curl refer "http://manageiq.org/docs/reference/fine/api/overview/auth" and i successfully get response for authentication but im not sure what next step to make it autologin from the my application.

Flow of what im trying to do:
1. Click link from my application
2. Link will run function to request curl authentication using rest
3. redirect to manageiq URL upon successfully get token

Comment: just curious did you find a way to login to miq through api or curl

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refer to latest [documentation](https://www.manageiq.org/docs/reference/latest/api/reference/authentications) 
If I get correctly your question, you may just define your login and password as an env variables (or read it from some file if you prefer this) and include this in your function.